# C++ string compress

Tags: c++, string

I wrote a program to compress a string using the counts of repeated characters. if the compressed string is longer than the original string, then we still return the original string. Below is my program:

```
void stringCompress(char* src) {
    char* original;
    original = src;
    char* rst;
    rst = src;

    int histogram[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        histogram[i] = 0;
    }
    int length = 0;
    while (*src != NULL) {
        length++;
        src++;
    }
    src = original;
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        histogram[(int) src[i]]++;
        if (histogram[(int) src[i]] == 1) {
            rst[j] = src[i];

            j++;

        }

    }
    rst[j] = '\0';

    char* final;

    rst = original;
    int index = 0;
    char buffer[33];

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {

        final[index] = rst[i];

        stringstream number;
        number<<histogram[(int)rst[i]];
------->        //cout<<number.str()<<endl;
        char* temp = new char[number.str().length()+1];
        strcpy(temp, number.str().c_str());
        index++;
        cout<<temp<<endl;
        for(int k =0 ;k<number.str().length();k++)
        {
            final[index]=temp[k];
            index++;

        }

    }

    final[index] = '\0';
    src = original;

    if (index <= length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)

            cout<<final[i];
    } else {
        cout << src << endl;
    }

}
```

But strange thing is that if I leave the cout sentence `cout<<number.str()<<endl;` there (the arrow points to the sentence), then the output is right. For example, aaaabcdaa outputs a6b1c1d1 and aabcd outputs aabcd. However if I comment out `cout<<number.str()<<endl;`, then nothing is generated. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since this is basically a C function anyway, why don't you do it with `printf`? If you want to use C++ you should do it properly (with `std::string`s and a RAII style), only then does is really bring a benefit.

Comment: As a side note, your reader will not be able to correctly read strings that have digits (but then, I don't know what kind of strings you are compressing here. The algorithm is of no use for normal text, obviously).

Comment: I assume the string only contains letters. Actually I'm not sure what the algorithm is used for either, since it's basically an interview question. Yes now I know I can use printf instead of mixing char* and strings up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `final` is uninitialized in your code. When I initialize it with a memory buffer, then your program prints the desired output whether the line you pointed to is commented out or not.

Perhaps you meant to use `buffer` (which is unused) as memory for `final`, such as:

```
final = buffer;
```

Comment: Yes it solved the problem. However actually I cannot know how many characters the final will point to, so what I can do is only give a relatively large space to final, right?

Comment: You cannot know exactly how many, but it can be at most two times the length of the input string. The other possibility is to use a buffer the same size of the input string and check continuously in the for-i-loop whether the target string exceeds the source length, and stop and just return the source string in that case.